# Having issue parsing back to an int after removing a character in Python?

Tags: python

Here's the code that's giving me issues:

```
newI = int(str(i).replace(char, ""))
newJ = int(str(j).replace(char, ""))
```

I'm getting the issue in the first assignment. `i` and `j` are both two digit integers before this runs, and `char` has been assigned a value if it was found in either of them when they're parsed to strings. For instance, if `i` is `27` and `j` is `73`, I'm hoping to cancel out the `7`s. So I parsed to strings, found the character, and now I'm trying to parse back to ints with the character removed. I'm getting the error

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''.

Can anyone give me some tips? Here's some more code:

```
for j in range(10, i):
    for char in str(j):
        if char in str(i):
            newI = int(str(i).replace(char, ""))
            newJ = int(str(j).replace(char, ""))
```

Comment: *"I'm getting the issue in line 3"* Why did you only post 2 lines then? Based on the error I would say you pass an empty string to `int`.

Comment: Can you show more of your code? Showing the prints of the input always helps. It's really hard to tell what's wrong without more info, i lost my crystal ball a couple days ago..

Comment: Sorry, the line 3 bit is a typo. I meant to hit 1. I'll add some more code now.

Comment: empty string is not a valid int literal.

Comment: Ok, let's say `i` is `27` and `char` is `"2"`. Shouldn't `str(i).replace(char, "")` return `"7"`, which could then be parsed back to an integer?

Comment: `"55".replace("5", "") == ""` (empty)

Comment: Ah, I see. In that case, how could I only replace one instance of the character?

Comment: update your question or ask a new one. Mention what you have tried and what doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the count to 1:

```
"55".replace("5","", count=1)
```

Comment: I was just about to come back and say that I'd figured it out. Thanks.

Comment: just curious, what do you want your output to be if i == j?

Answer (score 0):

In your example you have two nested `for`-loops. Using set intersections will be more efficient, especially if you are doing a bunch of large `i, j` values:

```
strI = str(i)
strJ = str(j)

# remove any similar characters (once)
for c in set(str(i)) & set(str(j)):
    strI = strI.replace(c, "", count = 1)
    strJ = strJ.replace(c, "", count = 1)

newI = int(strI)
newJ = int(strJ)
```